# Книги по JS/React/Angular

Tags: javascript, книги

Ребята подскажите где можно скачать литературу по JS/React/Angular/ на русском бесплатно.По JS хотелось бы что нить про OOP JS,паттерны. Хотелось бы освежить теорию). В сети нашел некоторую литературу но то что хотелось бы все платно. Вот например Стоян Стефанов React.js Быстрый старт. Обыскался так и не нашел. Если подскажите буду благодарен)

Comment: [Чуть-чуть халявы](https://github.com/EbookFoundation/free-programming-books/blob/master/free-programming-books-ru.md#javascript).

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov,  не плохая халява)))) от меня лично, блольшое благодарю...

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, Спасибо огромное! Вы меня выручили, приятно что есть не равнодушные люди. Всего вам хорошего всех благ)

Comment: Владимир Мартьянов Вам тоже спасибо за отзывчивость.

Answer (score 0):

Книги не посоветую, но русские веб сайты с описанием по **React** может быть пригодятся.

1. **Metanit** https://metanit.com/web/react/1.1.php
2. **learn-reactjs.ru** https://learn-reactjs.ru/home

И по **JavaScript**

1. **javascript.ru** https://learn.javascript.ru/

Так же рекомендую к этому относиться не как к теории а как к практике, если читать это как теорию то мало что закрепится, читаете и сразу пробуете использовать, причём по каждой отдельной функциональности сразу проверяете в коде, тогда знания пройдут через тело и запомнятся.

Comment: Спасибо большое Вы меня выручили. Я если честно многое уже сам нашел но есть материал который тоже пригодиться.Спасибо)

Comment: Пожалуйста. Кстати тут можно поставить лайк сообщению, если оно вам помогло и понравилось, и даже отметить как ответ.